# Placing items at top of collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ, I'm looking to place items which match a certain criteria at the top of my collection. I've tried

```
myCollection.OrderBy(m => m.Foo == "Bar" ? 0 : 1);
```

but I'm having no luck. Does anyone have any ideas why this isn't working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: its working fine for me. what error are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add a record to return result in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499448/add-a-record-to-return-result-in-memory)

Comment: Yeh seem to work fine, just make sure you assign the result to a variable: `myCollection = myCollection.OrderBy(m => m.Foo == "Bar" ? 0 : 1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OrderBy()` and the other LINQ methods do not modify the collection they're called on; instead, they *return* a new collection.

Answer (score 1):

All of the LINQ "operators" like Select, OrderBy etc. do **not** change the collection they were called on but return a new one!

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is a [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) check out the [List<T>.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method. Alternatively, if you're dealing with an array, use the [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) method. Those methods will sort the collection in place.